# Should I Test my project on every device?

Tags: android, responsive-design

I'm concentrated on making my app work on any devices (with different screen sizes).
My first question : Should I make many -(prefix)dpi for each resource or It's recommended to specify the exact resolution for devices? (for ex. w720dp) what are the differences? does first solution work for all screen sizes with same density?
Second question: Should I create many resource files for supporting different kind of screens or there is an easier way? (for ex. to define android:toYDelta attribute for different devices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to test your app on every combined situations: screen size, resolution, version of os, version of sdk and...

Drawables: if possible, use vector drawables, otherwise provide drawables for screen resolutions: `mdpi`, `hdpi`, `xhdpi`, `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi`.

Layouts: If you want to support mobiles and tablets, use `Fragment`s and `layout` and `layout-large` folders.

Orientation: use `lyout-port` and `layout-land` if you want to support different layouts for land or port orientation.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to make resources for different resolution. Best way to do it is to add Image Asset with Image Asset Studio. It will create images for different resolutions (dpi) from one source image. Additionally, app will pick suitable resolution of mipmap for device dpi, so you don't need to worry about images resolution anymore.

You should test your app on few different devices with different dpi, because it may look not quite well, especially on low dpi device. But thanks to dpi, it makes much simpler to test it.

[Image Asset Studio example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHm5v.png) - I can't upload images yet, that's why I give link to image.

But there's one problem with mipmaps and Asset Studio. It will force to use images with 1:1 aspect ratio. But you can generate mipmaps and then replace them in directories for yours custom images with different aspect ratio and it will work just fine.

Here you can read more about mipmaps:

[Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html)

[More about dpi](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[Mipmap introduction](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/introduction-to-mipmap-drawables-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use dpi. and when it comes to testing the design or layouts use Emulators. In Android, studio Emulators are available for each screen size and for each type of device.

Comment: you mean I have to test my app on many devices by using Android Studio emulators and set demission's by testing the values?!

Comment: yes, and use Vactor assets to make Icons Images won't be able to zoom or shrink as the resolution of devices change.